# Create Temporary Index for bulk operation and Delete after its completed

Tags: sql-server-2012, optimization, bulk

I am moving bulk data to archive tables.

Some times query returns up to 4.5million records, which takes about 2:15 minutes for a table of 40 columns.

I want too increase the performance for the selection by **using a temporary non clustered index and drop that index after select operation**.

I am also setting data base logging to bulk logging while performing the bulk operation.

Will that really help, or it is even possible o not.

Any other suggestions are also welcome.

Comment: 2:15 for 4500 records? Or is that 4.5million? Is it just a simple `SELECT FROM <TABLE>` or are there joins? It seems very slow regardless of the indexing if it's just simply selecting 4,500 records from one table

Comment: @MarkSinkinson its 4.5million

Comment: The benefit would depend on the query, but you can easily check how much time the index creation adds to see if it's worth it initially.

Comment: Please add the schema of the source table and the query you use to move data.